# VLOOKUP task in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vlookup, lookup

I am needing some JS that can `Vlookup` a piece of information from an `XLSX` or `CSV` file.
My example is this:
I have a spreadsheet containing balances of accounts.
When a person logs into their account, the variable 'ACCTNO' is currently set as their account number (example - 95785879).

I would like this to lookup the information from my spreadsheet which is found at `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\AccountBalances.xlsx` and return the balance of the account as shown below. In this example. the returned number should be £4.19.

Screenshot of Excel File

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot access the local filesystem. You should consider putting this information in JSON format and declaring it in your JS code, or look at a server-side solution such as a database.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. I am able to store this data in a database no problems. Can you advise how i would go about doing a Vlookup there? thanks

Comment: That would entirely depend on the stack/framework you're using. I suggest finding some how-to articles to implement this

Comment: If you found the answer helpful could you please mark/upvote it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help, it won't let me upvote because i have a new account. Thanks anyway